# Need quick help with this Calculus problem

Tags: calculus

Really need help with this homework question but am unsure where to even begin.

"assume $z^2=3x+y^3-1$

Find the value of $dy/dt$ when $x=3,y=2,z=4,dz/dt=6$ and $dx/dt=2$"

any help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you know implicit differentiation?

Comment: @TimThayer:  This is more likely categorized as a "related rates problem" in the OP's textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly differentiating with respect to $t$, we have: $$2zz′=3x′+3y^2y′$$
Since $y'$ is what we need, we separate it from the rest to end up with $$ y' = \frac{2zz′−3x′}{3y^2}$$
Plugging in the values given, we have $y'=\frac{7}{2}$.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $x =3, y = 2\implies z^2 = 3\cdot 3+2^3-1 = 16 \implies z = ...\implies  2zz' = 3x'+3y^2y'\implies y' = \dfrac{2zz'-3x'}{3y^2}= ...$

Answer (score 0):

Hint-

$z^2=3x+y^3-1$

Differentiating w.r.t t,

$2z\frac{dz}{dt}=3\frac{dx}{dt}+3y^2\frac{dy}{dt}$

Now put values to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

Alright,thanks for all the answers and hints!

I got it! It's simple. I realize that all i have to do is take the derivative of the original which gives me 2z=3+3y^2

then substitute the given
(2)(4)(6)=3(2)+3(2)^2
48=6+12(y) 
Solve for y

42=12y
42/12=y
3.5=y or y= 7/2